# Реализация идиомы copy-on-write

Tags: c++, классы, ссылки, smart-pointer

В книге *Скотта Майерса* - *"Наиболее эффективное использование C++"* в правиле 29 приводится реализация группы классов для обслуживания пользовательского класса `Widget` посредством создания класса-обертки `RCWidget`, содержащего указатель `RCIPtr<Widget>` и перенаправляющие функции. Этот механизм соответствует современному `std::shared_ptr` за исключением того, что в механизме Майерса имеется возможность при изменении данных по указателю отделить его от остальных и создать копию данных, т.е. значение разделяется до тех пор, пока его изменят в одном из указателей - тогда создается дополнительная копия.

**Вопрос** в том, является ли эта реализация приемлемой на современном стандарте C++ и, если нет, то в чем ее следует дорабатывать? Есть реализация такого надстроечного механизма в boost или еще где-то?

**P.S.** Код не приложил, просто под рукой только книга и телефон, а он на 2.5 стр. Если у кого-нибудь есть электронная версия - дополните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это copy-on-write, который много где применяется. Например, в Qt это повсеместно. Так в gcc был реализован `basic_string`, пока C++11 этого явно не запретил. В целом же, мне не совсем понятно, что Вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @ixSci спрашиваю, актуальна ли реализация в книге и не требует ли она каких-то кардинальных доработок и где можно найти реализацию этих классов? Я имею ввиду не из книги, а в какой-нибудь библиотеке, чтобы подключать хедеры и пользоваться? + в книге упоминалась возможность автоматизированной генерации RCWidget, может это сделано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дать однозначный ответ нельзя.

С одной стороны, более распространённым является *intrusive*-подход, когда объект сам управляет разделением своих данных (и, соответственно, хранит в себе указатель на внутренний контейнер с ними). Это обосновывается инкапсуляцией и отсутствием лишних сущностей.

С другой же стороны, любой *intrusive* нарушает принцип «один класс — одна сущность», смешивая воедино основную функцию и диспетчер управления данными. К тому же, он *обязывает* программиста к постоянному использованию данного механизма, даже когда он избыточен.

Так что приемлемость того или иного подхода зависит от конкретной ситуации. Где-то применимы классы-обёртки, где-то — внутреннее управление силами самого объекта.

Comment: А не подскажете, где посмотреть или откуда взять реализацию COW на std::shared_ptr? Посмотрел на хабре статью - там только наброски, на en.SO тоже. С Qt я не работал - может там есть этот шаблон как отдельный хедер?

Comment: @Jenssen, COW силами внешнего умного указателя в Qt называется «explicit sharing» (явное разделение) и реализовано в виде класса [`QExplicitlySharedDataPointer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html). Его исходный код можно посмотреть, например, в Github-зеркале репозитория Qt ([файл `qshareddata.h`, строка 135](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/3fe74b76fd0eaf39d4c6681e2edca5adbf107883/src/corelib/tools/qshareddata.h#L135)).

Answer (score 0):

Это называется copy-on-write.

Примерно такого же можно добиться с `std::shared_ptr<const T>`.

При модификации объекта его надо явно копировать, например

```
auto s = make_shared<const string>("foo");
auto s2 = s;
auto s3 = make_shared<const string>(*s + "bar");

auto s4 = make_shared<string>(*s);
s4->resize(4);
shared_ptr<const string> s5 = s4;
```

Если на объект указывают только `shared_ptr<const T>`, то бонусом идет потокобезопасность - объект никогда не поменяется.

Comment: Про `std::shared_ptr<const T>` не полностью корректно, если учесть что `T` может иметь `mutable` поля, которые можно модифицировать у константного объекта. Например тот же std::shared_ptr содержит внутри `mutable` счетчик ссылок.